# Segmentation fault (Core dumped) - simple

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a beginner in C. I got a simple program where I want to change every keyword into a corresponding number . For instance A = 0, B = 1 and F = 5 etc. In this case keyword "hello" will be "7 4 11 11 14".
I can compile this code, but whenever I run this I get the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I tried several things to change it, but without avail. Can someone please check my code and give me feedback? Any constructive feedback on my style, logic and other code related stuff are welcome as well!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

int keylength = strlen(argv[1]);
char *key = argv[1];

// insert keyword
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Less commands please.");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    if (!isalpha(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Please no numbers or weird symbols");
    }    
    else    
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
        {
            if(isupper(key[i]))
            {
                key[i] = key[i] - 65;
            }

            else if(islower(key[i]))
            {
                key[i] = key[i] - 97;
            }
        } 
    }               
}

}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a *pointer to `char`*, so I'm surprised the compiler doesn't yell at you for e.g. `isalpha(argv[1])`.

Comment: As for the crash, run in a debugger to locate it. Oh, and dereferencing a pointer before you know it's valid will most likely lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (example: you using `argv[1]` before you check if there *is* an `argv[1]`).

Comment: What is `string` defined as (probably a typedef in `cs50.h`)?  Just as an FYI for your instructor, that's probably a bad name to use as a typedef, since `string` is practically a keyword in C++ and will likely cause more confusion than be helpful (especially since it appears to probably be a typedef for `char*`; just use `char*` - it's actually less confusing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Must provide one argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int keylength = strlen(argv[1]);
    int i = 0;

    for( ; i <keylength; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("not alpha\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    char *key = argv[1];
    printf("b4 %s\n", argv[1]); 

    for (int i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(key[i]))         
            key[i] = key[i] - 65;
        else if(islower(key[i]))    
            key[i] = key[i] - 97;
    } 

    printf("after %s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Things to note.

1. Don't try to access `argv[1]` until you know `argc` is at least 2.
2. You need to check each char in `argv[1]` against `isalpha` in a loop. Not just pass the string pointer directly to `isalpha`.
3. Also note that you are altering the command line arguments memory directly. Whilst its possible to do, its a dubious practice. It would be better to make a copy of `argv[1]` and alter that. I have not implemented this in my example.

Comment: No prob. Feel free to accept if it's the answer you were after.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha` accepts a character as an input, not a pointer to a character (or string, as you have done). You need to loop through the string and check each character individually. I'm not sure if that would cause a segfault though...

Another possible problem: When you run the program, are you running it with an argument?

If not, then `int keylength = strlen(argv[1]);` will cause a segfault as `argv[1]` doesn't exist. You should really put this in the `else` clause after checking the number of arguments.